# Graphql schema for Relay gets cached somehow by webpack (?)

Tags: webpack, relay

So the problem is simple. I am using webpack and relay, and when I update my schema by command bundle gets rebuilt but when I'm trying to query updated fields I'm getting error:

> GraphQL validation error `Cannot query field "X" on type "Y".` in file `Z`. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added.

But schema is updated and i can see this field. So can i clear cache somehow to prevent this. Just rebuilding bundle doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in my case content of folder .happypack was the reason of this behaviour. So `rm -rf .happypack/*` solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I had the same issue recently. The problem is babel-loader plugin doing some type of caching. Setting `cacheDirectory` option to false fixed it for me. This is my webpack module rule for jsx after the fix:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        cacheDirectory: false,
        plugins: [path.join(__dirname, 'loaders/babelRelayPlugin')],
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same with a persistent call stack error referencing a non-existent line in a file - even after removing the file from the project. The webpack builds were succeeding fine (running with option --cache false), but the error showed as coming from the webpack output file in all browser dev consoles. I tried removing the file before each build to make sure it used the newly generated version to load the app, but the error wouldn't clear. I finally had to create an entirely new project directory on the host from the ground up, reinstall all the node packages and the app - at which point it loaded fine so something was obviously cached somewhere other than in the output file...

Comment: You suggesting rebuild project from a scratch?